# How to do a partial postback for a webpart on a SharePoint page

Tags: development, web-part, postback

What are best practices for doing a partial postback?  Is it okay to use an AJAX Update Panel?  I have a number of webparts on a page.  I need to do a page refresh, so one webpart on the page gets refreshed.  If possible, I would like to just postback the one webpart (partial page)and not the entire page.  If using an AJAX Update Panel is not suggested, can I do it using JQUERY?  If yes, I am wondering how I can do this?

Thanks for any tips given...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have too many best practices about partial postbacks withing sharepoint. I would advise to go with JQuery: UpdatePanel won't work in sandboxed solutions

Comment: Do you happen to have an example or know of an online post that shows how to do this using jquery?

Comment: Chris O'Brien wrote a series of blogposts on jquery and SharePoint 2010: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/10/sp2010-ajax-part-1-boiling-jquery-down.html

Comment: IMO, it is perfectly OK to use an UpdatePanel if you aren't using sandboxed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A "partial postback" is usually an AJAX interaction; you're sending a small amount of data to the server and getting some data back without sending the whole page. It makes the UX more what people are getting used to on the "modern" Web. You can use jQuery's AJAX function to make this happen.